# which one to choose between calling a function twice and storing the return value in a variable?

Tags: java, optimization

I have the following scenario.. and I come across the similar scenario many a times. Which is more preferable of the following two options?

*Option-1:*

```
String result = ( getDetails(...) == null ) ? "" : getDetails(...);
```

*Option-2:*

```
String returnValue = getDetails(...);
String result = ( returnValue == null ) ? "" : returnValue;
```

Which is more preferable and/or a good practice.?

Comment: can you control the `getDetails(...)` method?

Comment: option 2 is better readable. Furthermore you call getDetails only once.

Comment: You probably meant `String result = returnValue == null ? "" : returnValue;`. And the better solution would probably be to make sure that `getDetails` never returns `null`.

Comment: Never code for performance, code for readability http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923795/java-method-invocation-s-using-a-variable

Comment: Is `getDetails(...)` say idempotent ?

Comment: @assylias: yes. i meant '=='. corrected the same. :)

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: Yes it is. Thanks for all your views and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Option-2:* is better

*Option-1:* Results in extra method call and such cases should **always be avoided** unless `getDetails(...)` is a getter method (a one liner method which returns something)

If you dig down to micro optimization, a method call generally results in

- allocation of stack for the method variables
- jumping the instruction set

which are couple of many overheads. [As many say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923795/java-method-invocation-vs-using-a-variable), such performance optimization should be left to Compiler and the code should be written to be more readable.

Comment: Hi Sanbhat. Can I have a question relates to this post? I am not talking about Performance (CPU time consuming). I am talking about Memory consuming. As I know, for each getter call, JVM need to create a new Stack so my question is Do you think Option 1 will consume more memory than Option 2 ( I assume that getDetails called a lot )? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

*Imho* The second one is better because it's  avoiding calling `getDetails(...)`  method twice.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do that check for every call of `getDetails` then the best way would be `getDetails` method to return `""` in cases when you return null.

Also calling the same method twice (which is probably idempotent in your case) is not a good practice even if it is very simple.

Please read this [java-how-expensive-is-a-method-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495030/java-how-expensive-is-a-method-call). Main idea is don't do premature optimization, but you should get used to these simple cases when you can write better code

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But, the example was chosen randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer the second option because it is more readable, especially when using the ternary operator.

If it is a problem or not to call `getDetails(...)` twice depends on your method. If it is a simple getter, the JVM might optimize the call and directly use the value so storing it in a local variable does not make a difference.
If it is a more complex method, e.g. a query to the database, I would definitely store the result in a local variable.

Generally speaking: Care about code readability first! If you find performance problems later on, try optimizing then.

Answer (score 0):

option-2 will be always optimized one what ever you wrote in the calling function.
Even if you are writing any in-build function or expression two times it will take fraction of section more than option-2.