# What is fastest way to get minimum of two or more integers in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have two integers like `val a = 5` and `val b = 7`. I just got curious about what is the fastest way to compute the minimum of these integers.

```kotlin
val min = minOf(a,b)
```

```kotlin
val min = Math.min(a,b)
```

```kotlin
val min = if(a<b) a else b
```

Can you tell me which one is faster and why that is faster?

Comment: Most likely they all have the exact same speed. `minOf` is the exact same as `Math.min` since it's inlined, and `Math.min` uses the same logic as in your third block. Function calls are often optimized, the compiler may even inline it so there would be no difference at all. I suggest you read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495096/5288316. Also, if you really care about performance to that point, don't use the JVM...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are all equally fast.

If you look at the definition of the `minOf()` function, you see

```
/**
* Returns the smaller of two values.
 */
@SinceKotlin("1.1")
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public actual inline fun minOf(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    return Math.min(a, b)
}
```

that is, in fact, your second option.

Then, the body of `Math.min()` is

```
/**
 * Returns the smaller of two {@code int} values. That is,
 * the result the argument closer to the value of
 * {@link Integer#MIN_VALUE}.  If the arguments have the same
 * value, the result is that same value.
 *
 * @param   a   an argument.
 * @param   b   another argument.
 * @return  the smaller of {@code a} and {@code b}.
 */
public static int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

that is, in fact, your third option.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the overhead of a function call might not be significant.

Answer (score 4):

KOTLIN 1.8.0

The latest one is below and working fine.

1. **Latest :    `a.coerceAtMost(b)`**
2. Deprecated but still can use : `Math.min(a, b)`
3. Legacy : `if(a>b) b else a`

have a good day !